# Error rezipping a powerpoint folder into a pptx on mac

Tags: macos, powerpoint

I am attempting to manually edit an embedded powerpoint workbook on macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (as a test to later automate the process using STATA and/or Bash).

My process is this:

1. Rename a completed powerpoint, PresentationName.pptx, to .zip

   2. unzip PresentationName.pptx.zip using Unarchiver (success!)
   3. Navigate folder structure to edit a few numbers in excel embedded workbook
   4. Attempt to rezip (using context menu "compress", or terminal)
   5. Attempt to open PresentationName.pptx (errors)

In terminal:

```
zip -r rezip1/PresentationName.pptx PresentationName.pptx -x "*.DS_Store"
```

The new .pptx file is created in the folder specified. From here, I am expecting the powerpoint to open up normally, with my new changes reflected in the embedded workbook.

Instead, I receive two errors:

> PowerPoint found a problem with content in PresentationName.pptx.
>   PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation.If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair.

after clicking Repair,

> Sorry, PowerPoint can't read PresentationName.pptx.

I'm guessing the terminal based zipper zips an incorrect file type/structure, but not sure if that is the case and was hoping someone had some success here.

Thank you for reading and apologies for any stupid questions/format mistakes I may be presenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rezipping OOXML files is tricky. I've have success working on a external hard disk that doesn't create .DS_Store files to begin with. In Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

In addition, the macOS Archive utility never produces a workable OOXML file either. Using zip in Terminal should get around that.

For non-programmatic editing, [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html) 11 or better can work directly on OOXML files without unzipping them. The [OOXML Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn?hl=en) add-in for Chrome can also do this, and for free.

Comment: Thank you, John! That defaults write command in Terminal really did the trick! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Zipping works when being in the root folder of the unzipped contents (and excluding .DS_Store as you are already doing). Full example of unzipping and zipping a presentation that produces a correct file named `PresentationName-repacked.pptx`:

```
mkdir PresentationName
cp PresentationName.pptx PresentationName/
cd PresentationName
unzip PresentationName.pptx
rm PresentationName.pptx
zip -vr ../PresentationName-repacked.pptx ./ -x "*.DS_Store"
```

Here are two shell scripts for unpacking and packing PowerPoint files on Mac:

**unpack-pptx.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: ./unpack-pptx.sh PresentationName.pptx

NAME="${1/.pptx/}"

set -e
set -x

mkdir "$NAME"
cp "$NAME".pptx "$NAME"/
cd "$NAME"
unzip "$NAME".pptx
rm "$NAME".pptx

exit 0
```

**pack-pptx.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: ./pack-pptx.sh PresentationName.pptx
# Note: Expects the unpacked directory (created with unpack-pptx.sh) to be available

NAME="${1/.pptx/}"

set -e
set -x

cd "$NAME"
zip -vr ../"$NAME"-repacked.pptx ./ -x "*.DS_Store"

exit 0
```